# WPF, property bound to dependent ComboBox always gives initial value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that needs to depend on the value of another `ComboBox`.  This part already works, with the dependent `ComboBox` refreshing when a new value is chosen in the independent `ComboBox`:

```
<!-- Independent -->
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
          x:Name="cbo_product" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productsXml}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="@name" SelectedValuePath="@name"
          SelectionChanged="cbo_product_SelectionChanged"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Product}" />

<!-- Dependent -->
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
          x:Name="cbo_component" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="201"
          DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbo_product}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Components/Component}"
          DisplayMemberPath="@name" SelectedValuePath="@name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Component}"
          SelectionChanged="cbo_component_SelectionChanged" />
```

In the C# class behind this, I have:

```
public MyUserControlConstructor()
{
    MyViewModelInstance= new MyViewModel();
    DataContext = MyViewModelInstance;
}
```

And in `MyViewModel`, I have:

```
public string Component
{
    get { return _component; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _component)
        {
            return;
        }
        _component = value;
        onPropertyChanged(PropertyNames.Component);
    }
}

private void onPropertyChanged(PropertyNames fieldName)
{
    if (null == PropertyChanged)
    {
        return;
    }
    string propertyName = Enum.GetName(typeof(PropertyNames), fieldName);
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

When I change the dependent `ComboBox` (Component), it shows up with the new value in my app, of course.  However, when I hit a button that causes the value of the `Component` property to be displayed, it is always the initial value, and not the value I just chose in the `ComboBox`.  I think there must be an error in my XAML.  For the C#, I tried to follow a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list) and [this guide](http://japikse.blogspot.com/2009/07/inotifypropertychanged-and-wpf.html).  How do I tie my dependent `ComboBox` to XML values nested in the `SelectedItem` of the independent `ComboBox`, but still update the `Component` property in my class?

**Edit:** my suspicion is that things are wonky because I set the `DataContext` for the dependent `ComboBox` in two places:  first in the constructor in C#, to my view model, and second in the XAML, to `DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbo_product}"`.

**Edit:** I had been setting initial values in the constructor to my view model class.  When I take out the initial value for the `Component` property, then even after I change the selected value in the dependent `ComboBox`, I still get no value from the `Component` property.  This pretty much just rehashes what I already knew:  the dependent `ComboBox` is tied to the independent `ComboBox` (it gets its data from the independent `ComboBox`, that is), but not to the `Component` property.

**Edit:** by request, here's a sample of my XML:

```
<Products xmlns="">
  <Product name="Awesomeness">
    <Components>
      <Component name="Component of Glory"/>
      <Component name="Component of Doom"/>
    </Components>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

**Edit:** I'm guessing a `MultiBinding` would be of use, after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848946/is-it-possible-to-bind-wpf-combobox-selectedvalue-to-multiple-objectdataproviders) and [this](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen/archive/2007/04/26/13020.aspx).

**Edit:** it seems like I should be able to get the dependent `ComboBox` to work without setting `DataContext`, just by using `ItemsSource`:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
                      x:Name="cbo_component" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="201"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo_product, Path=SelectedItem,
                          XPath=Components/Component}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="@name" SelectedValuePath="@name"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Component}"
                      SelectionChanged="cbo_component_SelectionChanged"/>
```

However, this doesn't work:  the dependent `ComboBox` is empty, instead of showing all the Component names.

Comment: Would be a little easier to follow if you outlined the data (XML?).

Comment: @Henk:  righto.  Updated my question with a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found of getting around this involves setting the ItemsSource in C# instead of XAML, which I would prefer *not* to do.  However, it works, and after a day and a half of banging on this, it's the best I came up with.

In XAML:

```
<!-- Independent -->
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
          x:Name="cbo_product" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productsXml}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="@name" SelectedValuePath="@name"
          SelectionChanged="cbo_product_SelectionChanged"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProductNode}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Product}" />

<!-- Dependent -->
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
          x:Name="cbo_component" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="201"
          DisplayMemberPath="@name" SelectedValuePath="@name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Component, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionChanged="cbo_component_SelectionChanged"/>
```

In C#, the event handler for when the independent `ComboBox` changes:

```
private void cbo_product_SelectionChanged(object sender,
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set ItemsSource of dependent ComboBox
    cbo_component.ItemsSource = getChildNodesFromComboBox(
        sender as ComboBox, "Components/Component"
    );
    cbo_component.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

// Helper method to do XPath query and get child nodes from selected value of
// independent ComboBox
private XmlNodeList getChildNodesFromComboBox(ComboBox comboBox,
    string xpath)
{
    if (null == comboBox)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var xml = comboBox.SelectedItem as XmlElement;
    if (null == xml)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return xml.SelectNodes(xpath);
}
```

Now the `Component` property in my view model class, to which my dependent `ComboBox` is bound in XAML, gets populated with the value selected in the dependent `ComboBox` because I didn't have to change the `DataContext` of the dependent `ComboBox`.